# Video stream over RF and converting to Wifi

Tags: rf, converter, wifi

So, here is the scenario: I have to put a camera far away from my wifi internet hub and want to see the video on my cell phone. I know that I can put Wifi repeaters, but it's not a feasible solution.

I was thinking if it's possible to have a camera transmitting the video using RF (radio frequency) and then convert into wifi, so then I could build an app and see/record the video from my cell phone.

I came to this idea after seeing Drones transmitting videos over Radio Frequency, but couldn't find anything on the internet.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I trust you understand that WiFi is a form of RF, right? I'm not sure what kind of distinction you're trying to make here.

Comment: at 900MHz, Recoton used to provide TX/RX pairs to link across a home.

Answer (score 1):

You have not stated a distance for the transmission.

WiFi is a form of RF signal, but based on what you are stating in your question, I think you meant that you want to send this video feed further than WiFi. You have a couple of options here. You could find a camera and an RF transmitter (obviously, one that has enough bandwidth and a transmission distance way further than what WiFi can reach) that can be connected to a microcontroller. Then on the receiving side, it's just a matter of picking up the transmitted signal and decoding it to be viewed to a phone.